# What can I improvise to slowly close a door?

Tags: doors

I have a hall door that I want to have automatically close slowly, not fast.  I've tried a proper door closer.  It was cheap but became very noisy fast.  The other issue with it is I have young children and the youngest had trouble pushing it open even though the strength was wound down.

Option 2: I found something I think would work.  Butterfly spring door closers.  These are put over the hinge pin.  However, getting them to NZ is a ridiculously expensive process.  A $3 spring wants US$30 - $60 shipping from Amazon or Ebay.  I can't find them on Ali Express which usually has free shipping to NZ.

Any other improvising options?  I was considering a weight, some strings and eyelets but that would look a little bit untidy.

Comment: Most "proper door closers" have a variety of adjustments.

Comment: The one I had and sold off had 2 adjustments.  I still couldn't get it light enough to the push.  But the worse thing is it was noisy.  Better ones are 2 or 3 times the price of what I paid.  So I'm looking for an altenative. I don't want to pay $60 for a spring! LOL

Comment: > 3rd party Amazon sellers > eBay > AliExpress ... I think I found your problem!   You seem drawn like a moth to a flame to the cheapest junk that fell off a truck in Shenzhen.  That $60 shipping is from *3rd party Amazon Marketplace sellers* who don't want to ship to NZ. Amazon proper won't sell it!   [Here is a spring closer at work](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LuO2dGa2pXg), note it does not slowly close a door, it slams it just like you'd expect a spring to.   If you want a real closer, buy a quality one from a reputable vendor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run a light chain from the frame to the door.  The attach a small weight to its center.

Comment: That is what I was thinking about.  I might consider it.  Although our little ones will probably try hanging on it.  I would use thin nylon braided string rather than chain.  It needs to be quiet.

Comment: Anything like this that moves slowly enough to not be a safety hazard to little fingers probably won't overcome the latch spring. It'll stop when the bolt touches the strike.

Comment: Would be better if it closed it.  A spring would get enough tension to probably just close it.

Comment: Did this in the end and it achieves the desired effect

Answer (score 0):

How about a gravity hinge?  Those are the hinges used on saloon doors.  Quiet, simple, slow closing.  Here is [one for $10 on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00EV7LI22).

[image]

Comment: Funny thing is when I tried to source some of these in NZ I couldn't get them locally.  So I tried Amazon/Ebay.  They were peanuts + $30-$50 in shipping.

Comment: @Matt:  Was that for overnight delivery?

Comment: nope.  Something that fitted into an envelope was really that expensive to send.